# How to get a sample when setting a condition with replace=False for those that contain smaller value than sample size

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a certain number of columns for each `ID` but I can't use for example .sample(n=30) because I would get a ValueError stating that `Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'`.

I know that if I make `replace` to `True` I would not get the error, but I don't want that. Instead for those `IDs` that don't have 30 rows, I want to take those that exist and not more.

What I am currently doing: `df = df.groupby('ID').sample(n=30)`

I tried also `df = df.groupby('ID').head(30)`, this gets the first 30 rows for each ID and only the rows available for the ones that do not have more than 30 rows. But it just takes the first 30 and it doesn't randomly pick them. Therefore, it does not work for my case.

I tried `.frac` but that doesn't give the results I want.

Is there any other way to do this in a pandas df?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You could shuffle then take the groupby head? `df = df.sample(frac=1).groupby('ID').head(30)`

Comment: @HenryEcker Actually I think that worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to do the global shuffle that `frac(1)` would do, you could just use the size instead if it is smaller than `30` In order to avoid your problem with creating another `'ID'` columns you can tweak the settings of `groupby` a bit.

Create a new Test-DataFrame

```
In [30]: df = pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()

In [31]: df['ID'] = list(range(3))*6+[1,2]*6

In [40]: df['ID'].value_counts()
Out[40]: 
1    12
2    12
0     6
Name: ID, dtype: int64
    ...:
```

Then you can use `apply` to decide for each group how many samples you need

```
In [32]: df2 = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(min(8, len(x))))
Out[32]: 
                 A       B       C       D  ID
20uv3SF4qh  0.8606 -0.8545 -0.2261 -0.2144   0
vBOWE8VPBL  0.9171  0.4375  0.9970 -0.9345   0
Kwzs4p5QYj -0.6896 -1.0051  0.9544  1.4635   0
XVfyETNO3g  0.4095 -1.2128 -1.5254  0.2521   0
l9zEX7eRM1 -0.4871  0.5637  0.9734  1.9705   0
...            ...     ...     ...     ...  ..
lk3ldIhrpr -0.1244 -1.0035 -0.3616 -0.5537   2
NASmNcsBH9 -1.4542  0.6159  1.1075  0.7623   2
nN7CEiMFbc -0.6539  1.2619  1.2009 -0.2582   2
Z6gqbZY5PK  0.1713  0.0299  0.4418 -0.6228   2
KgyzhcYa4w  0.7239  0.2294  1.4657 -0.2369   2

In [38]: df2['ID'].value_counts()
Out[38]: 
1    8
2    8
0    6
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: this could work better actually but it creates another column called ID which doesn't really suit my need in this case.

Comment: for me this is Genius!!! it works for my need. However, I don't understand how it works fully yet.